# List of Favorites Tags Questions

Tags: feature-request

There is some way in the SO site to list only the questions from my favorites tags?

I can access the list of all questions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions, and also I can access the list of all questions from one specific tag, i.e. from JS tag in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript., but there is a way to list all the questions from all my favorite tags?

If it's not, it's possible to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not linked to your existing Favorite tags, but you can set up a [Filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/) on the main Stack Exchange site to show questions from a specific site (or sites) with a set of tags.

---

If you have a lot of Favorite tags, or your Favorites are spread out over several sites, [Sha Wiz Dow Ard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190018/list-of-favorites-tags-questions#comment587973_190022) points out in the comments a much easier option than setting up a custom filter.   Just go to your [Stack Exchange Network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) → Filtered Questions → Select Filter → Favorite Tags.

Comment: Actually there is a shortcut in place: Network profile → Filtered Questions → Select Filter → Favorite Tags :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That is much better. It pulls in Favorite tags from all Stack Exchange sites too.

Comment: Yep, not sure when it was added but noticed it a while ago. :)